# Mapping Per Track

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live

I hope I can make this concise and understandable. I need to know if I can do this before I purchase an Ableton license. I currently am running a trial version of Ableton Live Suite.

If I have an instrument rack within a track that has an instance of let’s say Omnisphere. Within Omnisphere in multi-mode is a mixer that I can map each of the channels in Omnisphere with an external controller. If I duplicate that same track to another track, anything that I mapped in track 1 will move in track two as well. So, even if I am playing within the instance of track one, if I move the fader that changes the volume of first channel in Omnisphere, it will change the volume of the first channel in Omnisphere of track two as well.

What I want to do is have these tracks be mapped independently so that only when the current track is selected through a chain that the midi mapping will only change on that track and not affect any other tracks.

My current setup is:

Track 1 - Chain with the first chain pointing to song 1, the second chain pointing to song 2 via an external instrument rack.
Track 2 - Contains an instrument rack with sounds in Omnisphere in multimode that are used in song 1
Track 3 - Contains an instrument rack with sounds in Omnisphere in multimode that are used in song 2

Now, I can get this to work correctly if I put clips to turn off and on each track device via device on/off. The problem is that I lose the ability to gracefully change patches (without the sustain hanging or the notes cutting off) which I want.

I hope this all makes sense because I want to make sure this will do what I need it to before I buy Pro.

Comment: I understand the question. I had the same question for using an Arturia Keystep controller and different tracks of Arturia virtual instruments. I can't remember what I figured out for that but I still have the Live Set that I created for that saved to my desktop so let me fire that up in a couple hours and reverse engineer what I did.